# VB is not a member of 'String'

Tags: vb.net, string

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextSearch.TextChanged
    'attempting to allow search by last name
    Dim con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim Sql As String
    Dim data_reader As String

    con.ConnectionString = "PROVIDER = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Me._DeCON_12___2015DataSet.DeCon"
    con.Open()

    Sql = "SELECT [First Name 2015], [Last Name 2015] FROM  DeCon WHERE [Last Name 2015] = TextBoxLName.Text"
    data_reader = Sql.ExecuteReader()
    'ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    If data_reader.HasRows = True Then
        Do While data_reader.Read()
            lbfirstname.item = data_reader.Item("firstname")
        Loop
    End If
    data_reader.Close()
    data_reader = Nothing
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Okay I'm a total newbie, and I'm trying to make it so a user can search by last name in a textbox, and then have first names (of people with that last name) show up in a listbox. I was given this code (except for data_reader As String) and I know I can make it work, but I don't know how.

Here are the errors I'm getting:

1. 'ExecuteReader' is not a member of 'String'.
2. 'Has Rows' is not a member of 'String'.
3. 'Read' is not a member of 'String'.
4. 'lbfirstname' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
5. 'Item is not a member of 'String'.
6. 'Close' is not a member of 'String'.

Now...lbfirstname, I might be able to figure out. I assume I need to change the name to whatever makes sense. Is it referring to the textbox or the listbox?

The rest of it...I have no idea. I thought Close was a given, and assumed Read was. When I try to Dim * As String it's of no help, and I knew that wouldn't be right anyway. I'm connecting to an Access database, if that makes any difference.

I don't know enough VB to do so. I was voluntold to make it, and somehow managed most the other bits with little help. This is the last part I should have to do, and I need it done by tomorrow.

Comment: there is a real good (short, simple) example here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(v=vs.110).aspx  Basically, a string is just text, in your case SQL is the command you want the db objects to carry out. Same with the other errors.  I am not sure you want to be firing off queries everytime the user presses a key either.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm trying to make sense of it. Unfortunately, the Microsoft website is often just over my head enough to be more frustrating than helpful.

Comment: Programming is a exercise in precision.  You have learn about the types and objects you are using.  MSDN is quite authoritative in that regard.  For isntance, `lbfirstname.item` this looks like you are just making up properties you'd like there to be.  I linked that particular page because of the short, simple code example.

Comment: As for the firing off queries every time the user presses a key...you're right. That was supposed to be in the search button sub. What the hades?

Comment: Yep. I assume the lbfirstname.item is pseudocode he sent me because he didn't know my column names or textbox name. Unfortunately, I don't know which one he was attempting to refer to, and none of those is a label.

Comment: Is this a website, WinForms, WPF?  It would help to know the following: a) What platform you're targeting, b) what the name of the TextBox you're getting the last name from, c) the name of the ListBox you're putting the first name in.

Answer (score 1):

The errors you are getting are because you're attempting to call properties and methods that are not part of the `String` class, as has been mentioned in the comments.  Specifically:

1. `ExecuteReader` is a method of `OleDbCommand`.
2. `HasRows` is a property of `OleDbDataReader` (which is returned by calling `OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader()`.  `Read()` and `Close()` are methods on the `OleDbDataReader`.
3. `lbfirstname` is not the ID assigned to the `ListBox` control in your application - you need to use the ID you gave the control.
4. `Item` should probably be `Items` (note the plural), referring to the collection of items in the `ListBox`.
5. You're vulnerable to SQL injection (in addition to the fact that your SQL string won't work anyway, because you use `TextBoxLName.Text` as a literal when you want the value of the `TextBox` instead.  To avoid SQL injection, you should be using parmaterized queries.
6. `lbfirstname.item = data_reader.Item("firstname")` - Even if this line of code worked, you'd only wind up with the last firstname in the collection returned from your database.  You need to add the first names to the `ListBox` via the `Add` method.

Putting this altogether, you would have something like this:

```
Using con As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("PROVIDER = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Me._DeCON_12___2015DataSet.DeCon")

    con.Open()
    Dim Sql As String = "SELECT [First Name 2015], [Last Name 2015] FROM  DeCon WHERE [Last Name 2015] = @LastName"
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(Sql, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBoxLName.Text

    Using data_reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If data_reader.HasRows Then
            Do While data_reader.Read()
                lbfirstname.Items.Add(data_reader.GetString(0))
            Loop
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```

Explanation of the above code:

First, the connection is wrapped in a `Using` block - this will ensure the connection is properly closed and disposed of when the block is exited, even if an exception is thrown.

Next, the `Sql` string is parameterized by replacing the value in the `WHERE` clause with `@LastName`.  The `OleDbCommand` is created and assigned the `Sql` string plus the `OleDbConnection` object.

The `@LastName` parameter is then added to the command's `Parameters` collection and assigned the value of the `TextBoxLName`.

`ExecuteReader` is then called on the `OleDbCommand` object, in a `Using` block again (to ensure the reader is properly closed and disposed of).

While the reader is looped through, the first name of each record returned from the query is added to the `ListBox`.  I used the `GetString` method of the reader to return the value as a string.  This method requires an ordinal (the index of the column), which based on your provided SQL string is the first column (0 since it's 0-indexed).

All of the above code assumes the column names in the query are correct and the control names are correct - you may need to adjust them to match what you have in your application.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for helping. I realized I had to put Imports...OleDb.OleDbDataReader at the top, and that solved most of the issues. I put the code where it BELONGED (in the button sub), and at this point I'm only getting this error: "An Unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in SystemData.dl" in debug, on ExecuteReader()

Hopefully I'll have it resolved soon, and I can post the code once I get it working for posterity's sake, if anyone thinks it would have any value at all.